# Running a C program in Visual Studio Code (or VS2019)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

I've just downloaded VS Code, and am struggling to work out the basics of running any programs. I'm attempting to run a basic Hello World program in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

I found out that I needed to download a C compiler to run C programs on VS-Code, so I downloaded Visual Studio with C++ [from the Microsoft website](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/), which basically installed Visual Studio 2019. The heading on the link said "Develop C and C++ applications", so I figured it would at least let me program in C.

After doing this, in VS-Code I downloaded the C/C++ extension from Microsoft, and the Code Runner extension by Jun Han, which was recommended by a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQTrs5G0H5c). I then selected the Run Code (...environment? application?), and pressed the Play button on the top-right. The output in the terminal was:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Leo\Documents\VSC Test Project\" && gcc test.c -o test && "c:\Users\Leo\Documents\VSC Test Project\"test
'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.078 seconds
```

I don't understand the error - so I opened Visual Studio 2019 to see if I could develop C applications in that. But no, only C++. Did Microsoft lie to me, or is there something else I need to do to configure C in VS2019?

Basically, I have no idea what I'm doing in VS-Code, and would really appreciate someone taking the time to break down how to actually run a program in there, and get C working. Or if there's a simple solution that allows me to write C in VS-2019, that would be equally great.

Comment: With VS there's a compiler config setting that controls whether it adheres to C or C++ standards, but Microsoft basically stopped support C decades ago, so you're better off using almost any other compiler, unless you really know what you are doingl.

Comment: The error you posted indicates VS-Code is trying to run the gcc compiler and can't find it.

Comment: GCC is a different compiler (from the MSVC compiler), and apparently the Code Runner uses it by default. So you can either install and setup a version of the GCC compiler for Windows (look into MinGW-w64, TDM-GCC, or MinGW), or you will need to configure the Code Runner to use the MSVC compiler instead.